# If we define $\|f\| = \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |f(t)|$, why this is not define as a norm

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C(\mathbb{R}) = \{ f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} : f $ is  a continuous function$\}$.

**Personnal question :** For $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$, if we define $\|f\| = \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |f(t)|$, why this is not define as a norm.

Is it necessary that $f$ has to be a bound function? Also I blocked on the principal question for a while. Is anyone is able to answer this question rigorously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your function $\|f\|: C(\Bbb R)\to \Bbb R$ is not well defined.

If $f(x)=x$ then what is $\| f\|$? Yes. You need the functions to be bounded to have a norm (in your sense).

Answer (score 0):

There are continuous unbounded functions on unbounded sets. So your "norm" is not real-valued, which is a requirement for a norm.

If you take bounded functions, then everything is OK (the space in question is a subspace of $L^\infty$, in fact).